# Is there a symbol for "as long as" in math?

Tags: notation

Let's say we have the expression

> $$∀,∈ℤ:=⟹=$$

Which means "for all values of  and  in the set of integers, if  equals  then  must equal ."

For example, if 4×6=4×6, then 4=4.

However, this does not apply to 0.

For example, 7×0=6×0, but 6≠0.

Is there a way to add to the previous expression a term that says "as long as x doesn't equal 0"?

Comment: Yes, then we write $\forall a,b\in \Bbb Z$ and for all $x\neq 0$ we have that $ax=bx$ implies $a=b$ by cancelling.

Comment: There are a few ways to do this; in your example, you could instead say $\forall a,b\in\mathbb{Z}, ax=bx\implies (a=b\lor x=0)$ (where $\lor$ is read as "or"), or equivalently $\forall a,b\in\mathbb{Z}, ax=bx\land x\neq0\implies a=b$ (where $\land$ is read as "and").

Comment: "a term that says "as long as a or b doesn't equal 0"? Be careful, you want to cancel $x$, which should be nonzero. You don't have to assume anything else on $a$ and $b$.

Comment: @DietrichBurde Ah, you're right. Sorry, I meant to say as long as x doesn't equal 0. Thank you for pointing that out!

Comment: Then the answer is easy - just add another $\forall x\neq 0$ in front. And say, what kind of number $x$ should be, e.g., $x\in \Bbb Z$, or $x\in \Bbb F_p(T)$.

Comment: Or: $∀{,}{∈}ℤ\;\:∀x{∈}\mathbb R{\setminus}\{0\}\;\;(=⟹=).$ The colon is [unnecessary](https://math.stackexchange.com/a/4412936/21813).

Comment: @ryang Yes, this is what I wanted to say! Only perhaps $x\in \Bbb C\setminus 0$ instead, or whatever domain we are considering.

Comment: @ryang Ah, I see! Thank you for clearing this up! :D

Comment: Now that I think about it, "∀,∈ℤ:≠0⟹(=⟹=)" works.

Answer (score 4, accepted):

There is no formal symbol for this. Even if there were, words are usually easier on your reader than formality. So write

> If $x \ne 0$ then $ax= bx \implies a =b $.

You could write

> $ax= bx \implies a =b $ provided $ x \ne 0$.

but that might make your reader hesitate and wonder until they finished the sentence. It's kinder to state the condition first.

The Ruby programming language has an [`unless` keyword](https://www.geeksforgeeks.org/ruby-unless-statement-and-unless-modifier/) that can follow the statement it references, so you could code something like

```
you can cancel x unless x is 0
```

Comment: $\forall \{ a, b, x \} \in \mathbb{R} \wedge x \neq 0, a x = b x \implies a = b.$

Comment: @DavidG.Stork That's correct, of course, but much harder to read than the same thing written out mostly in English.

Comment: Or: $∀{,}{,}x{∈}\mathbb R\;(x\ne0\land =⟹=).$ @DavidG.Stork

Comment: Btw, do "as long as" and "provided that" both simply mean "if", or are there exceptions? Some online dictionaries claim that "as long as" mean "only if", but then again they anyway seem to variously think that "only if" means "if" or sometimes "iff".

Comment: @ryang Yes, but see my response to David Stork. This is all part of my campaign to convince students that "prove it" does not mean "write it using formal logic".

Comment: @ryang Those are both perfectly good synonyms for "if". Choose what reads best in any particular argument.

Answer (score 0):

You could use "as long as $x$ does not equal $0$" like so:

With $\forall x \neq 0$ at the end:

> $∀a,b\in\mathbb{Z}:ax=bx\implies a=b, \forall x \neq 0$

or with $\forall x\in\mathbb{Z}^*$ at the end:

> $∀a,b\in\mathbb{Z}:ax=bx\implies a=b, \forall x\in\mathbb{Z}^*$

or with $\forall x\in\mathbb{Z}^*$ at the beggining:

> $∀a,b\in\mathbb{Z} \wedge \forall x\in\mathbb{Z}^*:ax=bx\implies a=b$